# define alternative rules with snakemake

Tags: snakemake

Hello I am new with snakemake and I need some help.

My goal is to index a genome (with bowtie2)
But I need some alternative steps depending of the files that are available

```
1> check if index already exist in storage (/storage/index)
2> if yes, copy index in local (/index)
3> if no, create index in local (/index)
4> then copy new index in storage (/storage/index)
```

I managed to setup a bash script to check the existing file and the alternative workflows. But I wish to use snakemake and I am not sure how to define the rules to obtain a similar behavior.

Comment: I would suggest showing what you have tried so far and where you ran into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your psedocode logic, as it is, seems to create cyclical dependency problem in snakemake. So to make it simpler, I changed step3 to `if no, create new index in storage (/storage/index)` and this allows step4 to be same as step1.

```
rule create_index:
    input:
        "/storage/index/a.fa"
    output:
        "/storage/index/a.idx"
    message:
        "Create index at source dir"
    shell:
        '''
        index_tool {input} {output}
        '''


rule copy_index:
    input:
        "/storage/index/a.idx"
    output:
        "/local/index/a.idx"
    message:
        "copy index to local dir"
    shell:
        '''
        cp {input} {output}
        '''
```

Comment: I get your point. But in my setup I cannot create the index directly in storage. I need to create the index in local then copy into storage.

Comment: I assumed this would be possible because of your step4. An ugly workaround is you exclude `input:`, just define `output:`, and let your bash script do the job for you. Of course, you will be missing out on snakemake's advantages.